# Local network works but not the internet

Tags: networking, 16.04, xubuntu, internet

I am at work and the Internet works fine on my laptop but then it suddenly stopped working and still does not work. I can get Local Net. No idea why this issue has happened. I do recall an update that occurred but I doubt this is the cause because my wifi and Ethernet work at home perfectly fine.

I am running xubuntu 16.04 LTS

Let me know if there is any other info needed.

UPDATED:

Here is the [Ubuntu Pastebin Link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/17990029/)

Comment: Please run the ubuntu forums wireless script (github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info) and paste the results into paste.ubuntu.com then edit your question to include a link to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to solve the issue identifying IPv6 as the culprit. When all other options failed, It appears that disabling it brought the connection back to working order.

If you happen to have this same issue in accordance to the specs I have provided, disable IPv6 on the network.